# Raising My Credit Score as a Student

Tags: credit-score

I'm still a student, and I:

1) Have been lucky enough to get a scholarship through my schooling and do not have student loans.

2) I currently live in a city without the need for a car (and actually, having one would be inconvenient for me personally, since parking is hard).

3) Do have a couple credit cards, with long history and (I think high) maximums. I don't need any more credit cards.

My credit score is steady ~765, but it has been there for a long time. Is there anything I can do to raise it without taking on unnecessary loans to pay them off?

Comment: Why do you think you need it higher? Do you plan on taking out a major loan (meaning house-sized, not car-sized) any time soon? It's more than high enough to reassure any employer who feels they have to check this.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking more car-sized. And it seemed not that high enough to me, but I didn't know what employers looked for. Thanks!

Comment: All employers generally care about is that you aren't managing your money so badly that you're going to cause them trouble.

Comment: Why no unnecessary loans? Having an installment loan is 10% of your credit score, which represents a much greater numerical boost to your score at these levels. You can take a $500 one out and autopay it. The amount compared to your other limits means nothing

Comment: @CQM: Given that Linda already has an excellent credit rating, and has no particular need for credit at this moment, I don't see any reason for her to do anything. Spending money to further optimize something which is more than good enough makes no sense at all. I've seen the "borrow something" advice many times, and maybe it matters if you're trying to repair your credit, but there are many of us who NEVER borrow and have top scores so I'm starting to really hate seeing it recommended blindly.

Comment: @keshlam I raised my FICO scores 70 points in two months using the above method. My credit history is young and I am not opposed to using money to maintain an exemption from socioeconomic problems. People trying to repair credit could possibly only eek 40, 50 or 60 points out of doing this (because their score is in the 400s, 500s of 600s), and they probably already have cash constraints so it would be more impractical to do. Having that installment loan boost the score also shelters your score from shocks if some other characteristic pulls down your score.

Comment: Not saying it won't work -- just saying that it isn't something everyone should be doing. Fine advice, but for the wrong person.

Comment: I've received that advice of borrowing a lot before. I didn't know how much it could help, or knew anyone who did it. Thanks for the info! I am kind of scared of taking out loans, but I'll definitely consider it more now.

Comment: You want to borrow money so that you have a high FICO that helps you borrow more money?  Stop borrowing.  You can get a mortgage with no credit score.

Answer (score 3):

Websearch says the numbers can be translated as:

```
630-689: Average (probably too much "bad" debt).
690-719: Good credit (little trouble getting loans, generally better rates)
720-850: Excellent
```

You have Absolutely Nothing to worry about. Really.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I just wasn't sure. I was also told it might be volatile since my credit score is young (and I know a lot of people with higher scores) , but I'll just leave it be.